# Easy C - Ignoring scanf()

Tags: c, getchar

I'm trying to learn C but am having difficulties with getting my program to recognize the `scanf()` function. I've included my code below and I'm sure it's some silly mistake - any guidance is very appreciated :)

```
int i = 0;
int boolean = 1;
while (boolean) {
    printf("Options\n1.Save\n2.Load\n3.Edit\n4.Quit\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    if (i==4) {
        boolean--;
        break;
    }
    else if(i <= 3 && i >=1) {
        /*will edit later - irrelevant*/
    }
    else {
        printf("Please enter a valid number");
    }
}
```

When I run the program the user isn't even prompted for a number - instead I get stuck in an infinite loop because boolean is never false. Why won't the program stop and take input from the user?

***EDIT***

I see now that it's more than relevant to mention that the twist with this code is that earlier on I'm redirecting STDIN from a text file (which I've just named filename ~ Thus from the command line when I run my program I'll type: ./myProgram < filename)
Is this the reason my program won't ask the user for more input as instead it goes to filename? I thought it would just read from the filename and then allow me to switch back to asking the user for numbers.

Comment: No problem is there. It is running fine.

Comment: That's probably because your `stdin` buffer is not empty and contains non-numeric character causing a matching failure each time.

Comment: If you type a non-numeric character (letter, punctuation other than `+` or `-`) as the first character, your `scanf()` is hosed.  It will repeatedly return `0`, which goes to the 'will edit later' part, and then goes back to prompt, but runs into the same problem again, and this keeps going for a while...  The fix is to *always* check the input function directly: `if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) { break; }`, for example.

Comment: i don't see any mistake in program itself, except that no <stdio.h> included, but i'm sure you did it up there, just not in this section. does the menu get printed or even printed repeatedly in your while loop?

Comment: Yeah, the menu is printed over and over

Comment: @Jerler Please post more code.

Comment: There's a non-numeric character stuck in the input buffer, then, and part of the fix is the test of `scanf()` as in my previous comment.  You can print a diagnostic message before the `break` (but inside the `{ … }`).  The non-numeric character must be left over from some previous input, so you've got a string that's too long or multiple words on a line of input but you used `%s` to read just the first word, or … One powerful diagnostic is to echo inputs immediately after you've got them.

Comment: This code should work, unless the input your user is typing in is broken. Also, this is completely irrelevant but you can save a couple of lines of code by ditching the `boolean` variable and just changing your while loop to `while(i != 4){}`.

Comment: well you can always replace scanf with fgets e.g. `char buffer[100]; fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin ); i = atoi(buffer);`

Comment: @Claptrap that still won't work if the user accidentally types an invalid character before the number-- the same issue as with using `scanf`. Although, I would still recommend using `fgets` instead of `scanf` for security reasons, such as potential stack overflows.

Comment: @gr3co: Claptrap's solution helps because it reads the broken input, whereas `scanf()` leaves the broken input behind.

Comment: I often wish that schools didn't try teaching `scanf()` and `fscanf()`; they are so damn tricky to use!  It is much easier to control things if you use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read whole lines and then use [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) to parse the resulting lines.  It is also crucial that they teach _'always test the result from input operations'_ (whether that's `fgets()` or anything else).

Comment: Post Edit: your code does not detect EOF, so yes, it is relevant that you redirected from a file. You must test that `scanf()` gets exactly the result you expect and break the loop if it doesn't.  That's the `if (scanf("%d", &i) != 1) { …report…; break; }` I've suggested.   ***ALWAYS*** check the result of `scanf()` — but you have to do it properly, as shown.  Checking against EOF is not correct; you can get 0 back instead of EOF. Test for the expected number of conversions.  By all means capture the return value and use that: `if ((rc = scanf("%d", &i)) != 1) { printf("Got rc = %d\n", rc); …`

Comment: ^ Agree, half of the C and C++ questions on this site seem to be about using formatted stream input functions and tokenization. They're not particularly intuitive and are difficult to get right, I imagine that beginner programmers may be turned off the subject by all the stumbling at this hurdle.  I'd rather see a course provide a pre-cooked input routine and have the student concentrate on simpler and more interesting things like processing the data read in.

Comment: Make sure you `#include <stdio.h>`; it's possible for your program to compile successfully but run erratically without it.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my XCode 5, Mac OSX Mavericks machine. if this is on main function, make sure you have return 0; line at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you ignore the return status from `scanf()`, your code will appear to ignore `scanf()`.

As noted extensively in the comments, your code should look more like:

```
int i = 0;
int boolean = 1;
while (boolean) {
    int rc;
    printf("Options\n1.Save\n2.Load\n3.Edit\n4.Quit\n");
    if ((rc = scanf("%d", &i)) != 1)
    {
        int c;
        printf("DEBUG: scanf failed: rc = %d\n", rc);
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
            printf("DEBUG: next character: %d (%c)\n", c, c);
        break;
    }
    if (i==4) {
        boolean--;
        break;
    }
    else if (i <= 3 && i >=1) {
        printf("DEBUG: i = %d\n", i);
        /*will edit later - irrelevant*/
    }
    else {
        printf("Please enter a valid number!\n");
    }
}
```

Note the debugging print in the section that is otherwise executed.

I've also added debugging printing to report on the characters left on the input line after `scanf()` fails.  Note that the preferred solution for such issues, using [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read the line and [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) to parse the line makes error reporting much simpler; you've got the whole line to report, not what's left after `scanf()` has mangled it.

This can be streamlined to avoid the variable called `boolean`:

```
int i = 0;
while (i != 4) {
    int rc;
    printf("Options\n1.Save\n2.Load\n3.Edit\n4.Quit\n");
    if ((rc = scanf("%d", &i)) != 1)
    {
        printf("scanf failed: rc = %d\n", rc);
        break;
    }
    if (i==4) {
        printf("read %d - quit\n", i);
        break;
    }
    else if (i <= 3 && i >=1) {
        printf("DEBUG: i = %d\n", i);
        /*will edit later - irrelevant*/
    }
    else {
        printf("Please enter a valid number!\n");
    }
}
```

The key point is testing the return value from `scanf()`.

---

#### xscan.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i != 4)
    {
        int rc;
        printf("Options\n1.Save\n2.Load\n3.Edit\n4.Quit\n");
        if ((rc = scanf("%d", &i)) != 1)
        {
            int c;
            printf("DEBUG: scanf failed: rc = %d\n", rc);
            while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
                printf("DEBUG: next character: %d (%c)\n", c, c);
            break;
        }
        else if (i == 4)
        {
            printf("Got %d - quitting\n", i);
            break;
        }
        else if (i <= 3 && i >= 1)
            printf("DEBUG: i = %d\n", i);
        else
            printf("Please enter a valid number! (got %d)\n", i);
    }
    printf("After loop\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror xscan.c -o xscan
```

#### Example 1

```
$ xscan < xdata.1
Options
1.Save
2.Load
3.Edit
4.Quit
DEBUG: i = 1
Options
1.Save
2.Load
3.Edit
4.Quit
DEBUG: i = 2
Options
1.Save
2.Load
3.Edit
4.Quit
DEBUG: i = 3
Options
1.Save
2.Load
3.Edit
4.Quit
DEBUG: scanf failed: rc = 0
DEBUG: next character: 120 (x)
After loop
$
```

#### Example 2

```
$ xscan < xdata.2
Options
1.Save
2.Load
3.Edit
4.Quit
Please enter a valid number! (got 0)
Options
1.Save
2.Load
3.Edit
4.Quit
Please enter a valid number! (got 5)
Options
1.Save
2.Load
3.Edit
4.Quit
Got 4 - quitting
After loop
$
```

#### xdata.1

```
1
2
3
x
```

#### xdata.2

```
0
5
4
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for helping clear this up. Everyone's logic makes sense, but when I use the code you gave me it still doesn't want to accept any input. Guess I have a particularly stubborn program...

Comment: You'll need to show your code more nearly completely, and the data file you're redirecting as standard input.  While I've not formally compiled the code I posted, I'd be rather surprised if it didn't work as I expected it to.  See also my update diagnosing what's left on the line you're trying to read.  For debugging, you almost can't have too much information.

Comment: OK: now I've formally compiled the code I posted, and I've updated my answer with a complete program that demonstrates the code working correctly with some input files, each of which includes both bogus and valid data.  (I've also run `xscan <<< "1 2 3"` and that behaves correctly too.)  Any further problems are because your code doesn't match mine in some significant way.  Testing with GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Comment: Holy cow - thanks so much for your help! I'll test it out, but if nothing else it already looks pretty impressive. 
Thanks!